# How to wrap around a sequence of non-blocking operation using reactive mono?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, reactor

I have a set of non-blocking operations which can start an operation, check if it's done and gets the result if it's done. The problem is that the `start` and `getResult` won't happen immediately together, but I need to return the result without blocking. Sample code below which demonstrates what I am trying to do.

```java
@GetMapping("/some-mapping")
public Mono<String> someops(@RequestParam(value="param") String someParam) {
    int jobId = nonBlockingOps.start(someParam); // 1. start the op
    return Mono.defer( () -> {
        // wait for op to complete
        while (!nonBlockingOps.isDone(jobId)) { /// 2. check if the op finished
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // This will block
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return Mono.error(e);
            }
        }
        return Mono.just(nonBlockingOps.getResult(jobId)); // 3. return the result
    } );
}
```

So, even though the mono is `defer`-ed, it might block when the subscription happens.

**1. So how do I wrap this around with `Mono` so that mono takes care of the waiting part?**

Alternatively (or additionally), you can consider three services as follows:

```java
@PostMapping("/job")
public Mono<Integer> opsStart(@RequestParam(value="param") String param) 
{ return Mono.just(nonBlockingOps.start(param)); }

@GetMapping("/job/isDone/{id}")
public Mono<Boolean> opsCheck(@PathVariable Integer id) 
{ return Mono.just(nonBlockingOps.isDone(id)); }

@GetMapping("/job/getResult/{id}")
public Mono<String> opsGet(@PathVariable Integer id) 
{ return Mono.just(nonBlockingOps.getResult(id)); }
```

**2a. So how do I achieve the same outcome by calling these functions?**

**2b. So how do I achieve the same outcome by calling these services via `WebClient`?**

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `Flux.interval` to periodically chack if the job is ready:

```
@GetMapping("/some-mapping")
public Mono<String> someops(@RequestParam(value="param") String someParam) {
    return Mono.just(nonBlockingOps.start(someParam))
            .flatMapMany(jobId -> Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofMillis(1000)).map(__ -> jobId))
            .filter(nonBlockingOps::isDone)
            .next()
            .map(nonBlockingOps::getResult);
}
```

2. Calling three services with a WebClient would look similar:

```
public class ApiClient {

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class Status {
        private int jobId;
        private boolean done;
    }

    private final WebClient client;

    public ApiClient(String baseUrl) {
        client = WebClient.create(baseUrl);
    }

    public Mono<String> getJob(String param) {

        return submitJob(param)
                .flatMapMany(id -> Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofMillis(1000)).map(__ -> id))
                .flatMap(this::getStatus)
                .filter(Status::isDone)
                .next()
                .flatMap(status -> getResult(status.getJobId(), String.class));
    }

    private Mono<Integer> submitJob(String param) {
        return client.post()
                .uri(builder -> builder.path("/job").queryParam("param", param).build())
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(Integer.class);
    }

    private Mono<Status> getStatus(int jobId) {
        return client.get()
                .uri(builder -> builder.path("/job/isDone/{id}").build(jobId))
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(Boolean.class)
                .map(status -> new Status(jobId, status));
    }

    private <T> Mono<T> getResult(int jobId, Class<T> clazz) {
        return client.get()
                .uri(builder -> builder.path("/job/getResult/{id}").build(jobId))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(clazz);
    }
}
```

To be honest, I cannot see much sense in polling the job status every second. I would probably at least return job progress and implement some kind of push-notifications (using WebSocket or Server-Sent Events).

The code above is not tested but it shows the general idea. Probably there are some things to be adjusted (request headers etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the job is not long running (*i.e. takes few seconds at max to complete*) IMHO the end result can be achieved making use of [DeferredResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html) instead.

The `DeferredResult` will help in async trigger of job, wait for its completion and return the result once available. Added advantage here is to specify job completion [timeout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html#DeferredResult-java.lang.Long-java.util.function.Supplier-) along with corresponding result!

Moreover you could leverage other life cycle callbacks viz. `onCompletion`, `onError` etc. to handle various conditions.

A typical controller would look something like below

```
@GetMapping("/some-mapping")
public DeferredResult<String> someops(@RequestParam(value = "param") String someParam) {

    DeferredResult<String> output = new DeferredResult<>(); // optionally supply the timeout value

    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        int jobId = nonBlockingOps.start(someParam); // 1. start the op
        // wait for op to complete
        while (!nonBlockingOps.isDone(jobId)) { /// 2. check if the op finished
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // This will block
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do something
            }
        }
        return nonBlockingOps.getResult(jobId);
    }).whenCompleteAsync((result, throwable) -> output.setResult(result));

    return output;
}
```

Do let know in comments if any more information is required.

**P.S.**: As noted by Mafor in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59592558/1910582) consider returning job progress and implement some kind of push-notifications (using WebSocket or Server-Sent Events).

Comment: What I am looking for is a **canonical solution** for the general problem statement of making three non-blocking calls into a single call without blocking any thread. Your solution may or may not block, and doesn't address the generality of the problem statement. Also, I don't want a design solution like returning a job progress since that doesn't address a generalised case either.